# deadlock in golang

Tags: go

I know by exchanging line 15 and line 17 gives no error, however, I don't understand why not exchange will gives deadlock

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"

)

func greet(c chan string) {
    fmt.Println("Hello " + <-c + "!")
}

func main() {
    c := make(chan string)
    //line15
    c <- "John"
    //line17
    go greet(c)

}
```

fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!

Comment: @sahaj: Votes are anonymous for a reason. Asking people to explain their votes is not constructive.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Your title asks about receive before send. Your question asks about send before receive. Your code does neither. What is your actual question?

Comment: I guess I had a bad title then (or poor english). The original question came from the confusion that:if I exchange line 15 and line 17, which will come first : c <- "John"  or <-c. It was hard for me to understand, at that time, "channel" will "give out" something before it "receives" (the case that <- c happens before c <- "John")

Comment: For an unbuffered channel, like you're using, send and receive must happen simultaneously. There is no "before" or "after".

Answer (score 3):

The channel `c` is unbuffered.  Communication on an unbuffered channel does not proceed until the sender and receiver are both ready.

The program deadlocks because no receiver is ready when the main goroutine executes the send operation.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

func greet(c chan string, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    defer wg.Done()
    fmt.Println("Hello " + <-c + "!")
}

func main() {
    c := make(chan string, 10)
    //line15
    c <- "John"
    //line17
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(1)
    go greet(c, &wg)
    c <- "Alex"
    wg.Add(1)
    go greet(c, &wg)
    wg.Wait()

}
```